# Get constraint in GADT-style declaration without specifically using constructor?

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, gadt

Consider the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, GADTSyntax #-}

data Test a where
    Test :: Ord a => { first :: a, second :: a } -> Test a

comp :: Test a -> Bool
comp (Test fst snd) = fst < snd
```

The constructor `Test` is declared with an `Ord` constraint. In `comp`, I've specifically taken a parameter constructed with `Test`, which gives the `Ord` constraint allowing me to use `<`

Now, suppose I wanted to write:

```
comp' :: Test a -> Bool
comp' x = (first x) < (second x)
```

Using the projection functions to get the first and second element. This is *not* okay because my parameter `x` was not (necessarily) constructed with `Test`, so there is no `Ord` constraint.

So, for my question, is there a way to take the parameter as just `x` but still somehow have the `Ord` constraint from the `Test` constructor, without having to "unpack" or pattern match on the `Test` constructor or add the constraint to my function?

As for why I would want this, I have a data type with a constructor taking many values, one of which I only need in this particular function, so unpacking it makes my function unnecessarily verbose:

```
myFunction :: Thing -> ...
myFunction (Thing _ _ _ _ need _ _) ...
```

As opposed to

```
myFunction t = ... (need t)
```

Comment: You could do `myFunction t@Thing{} = ...`.

Comment: `myfunction Thing{need=x}` This provides the `Ord` dict and you also have the value of the `need` field already unpacked into `x`.  There's also an extension that let you write `myFunction Thing{need}` and in the body you can use the name `need` to refer to the value of the `need` field of the argument.

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't know about that syntax!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function which extracts all of the constraints from the constructor:

```
data Test a where
    Test :: Ord a => { first :: a, second :: a } -> Test a

openTest :: Test a -> (Ord a => r) -> r 
openTest Test{} x = x
```

You can then write

```
comp :: Test a -> Bool
comp x = openTest x $ first x < second x
```

but note that the implementation of `openTest` is completely trivial - and it is less typing to just inline the pattern matching:

```
comp' :: Test a -> Bool
comp' x@Test{} = first x < second x
```

Note also this (i.e. the `Test{}` syntax) will work with any constructor, even if it is not a record constructor. Your actual function can simply be expressed as

```
myFunction t@Thing{} = ... (need t) ...
```

or equivalently

```
openThing :: Thing a -> (ThingConstraints a => r) -> r 
openThing Thing{} x = x 

myFunction t = ... (openThing $ need t) ...
```

Finally, you can also define a function to extract a specific field as well as the constraints which apply to this field, which can be very useful for large constructors with many constraints:

```
first' :: Test a -> (Ord a => a -> r) -> r 
first' t@Test{} x = x (first t)
```